# How do I get the title attribute as a variable to replace the hashtag in prettyPhoto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, title, hashtag, prettyphoto

I'm trying to replace the hashtag link of an expanded image with its title, rather than a numbered index.

I've managed to remove the unwanted numbering from the url but I don't know how to retrieve the title.

While editing the prettyPhoto javascript I've changed the SetHashtag function to this:

```
function setHashtag(){
    var title = pp_titles;
    if(typeof theRel == 'undefined') return; // theRel is set on normal calls, it's impossible to deeplink using the API
    location.hash = theRel + '/'+title+'/';
};
```

Using 'pp_titles' in the variable though seems to pull all the titles from the whole gallery and add them to the end of the url.  I just want to use the title for the current image but I'm unsure of where to retrieve it from.

You can see an example in any of the images here:  http://www.sghalliday.com/urban2.html

I would also try and like to remove the hashtag from the end of the url when the user exits the gallery but that's not such a big deal for now.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution, alter these lines in `prettyphoto.js` and you are good to go. If title is empty URL will look ugly, but will be still functional ;)

```
...
...

if(!pp_alreadyInitialized && getHashtag()){
    pp_alreadyInitialized = true;

    // Grab the rel index to trigger the click on the correct element
    hashIndex = getHashtag();
    ergec = hashIndex.split("/"); // add this line
    hashRel = hashIndex;

    //hashIndex = hashIndex.substring(hashIndex.indexOf('/')+1,hashIndex.length-1); // comment this line
    //hashRel = hashRel.substring(0,hashRel.indexOf('/')); // comment this line
    hashIndex = ergec[ergec.length - 2]; // add this line
    hashRel = ergec[0]; // add this line

    // Little timeout to make sure all the prettyPhoto initialize scripts has been run.

...
...

function setHashtag(){
    if(typeof theRel == 'undefined') return; // theRel is set on normal calls, it's impossible to deeplink using the API
    location.hash = theRel + '/' + pp_titles[rel_index] + '/' + rel_index +'/'; // alter this line
};

...
...
```